# How do I retrieve the count of distinct rows from each table in a join with T-SQL without knowing which fields are unique in each table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have inherited hundreds of Stored Procedures. Each Stored Procedure comprises more than a dozen joined tables and TVFs. 
This task, one among many, is to understand the Stored Procedures performance by looking at how many rows each table contributes to the final statement, with the non-negotiable difficulty that we don't know which column's values are unique in each table.

I'm using T-SQL with SQL Server 2014 and am used to Oracle. In Oracle i'd use something like rowid from each table and do a count of distinct values in the final joined query, as part of an analytical query, but I don't know of any similar field in T-SQL and all of the ways that I've searched for an answer has returned nothing

```
CREATE TABLE    #CUSTOMER       
(           
    C_ID    INTEGER ,
    NAME    NVARCHAR(10)    
)   ;       

INSERT INTO #CUSTOMER   VALUES( 1   ,   'AL'    );
INSERT INTO #CUSTOMER   VALUES( 2   ,   'BOB'   );
INSERT INTO #CUSTOMER   VALUES( 2   ,   'JOE'   );
INSERT INTO #CUSTOMER   VALUES( 3   ,   'SAM'   );

CREATE TABLE    #ORDER      
(           
    O_ID    INTEGER ,
    C_ID    INTEGER ,
    I_ID    INTEGER ,
    Quantity    INTEGER 
)   ;       

INSERT INTO #ORDER VALUES(10,1,20,4);
INSERT INTO #ORDER VALUES(11,2,20,6);
INSERT INTO #ORDER VALUES(12,2,21,6);
INSERT INTO #ORDER VALUES(13,2,21,6);

CREATE TABLE    #ITEM       
(           
    I_ID    INTEGER ,
    NAME    NVARCHAR(10)    
);          


INSERT INTO #ITEM VALUES(20,'FORK');
INSERT INTO #ITEM VALUES(21,'KNIFE');
INSERT INTO #ITEM VALUES(22,'SPOON');


select 
    count(distinct c.rowId), count(distinct i.row_Id), count(distinct o.rowId) 
from #CUSTOMER c
join #ORDER o ON
    c.C_ID = o.C_ID
join #ITEM i ON 
    o.i_ID = i.i_ID;
```

Expected Result:

cust_count | item_count | order_count

3       |   4        |  2

Unfortunately the statement above doesn't work as rowid has no meaning in SQL Server.

I can't do distinct count on C_ID, I_ID or O_ID because, as stated, I don't know if they're unique (which they're not in this fabricated case and hence produce the wrong result).

I can't do counts from all the individual tables as not all rows in the tables appear in the joins.

I can't use a window function as it'd mean re-writing the join statements, for hundreds of Stored Procedures, which is already enormous in any single case.

Ultimately what I want to achieve is an understanding that for a particular join, 1 billion rows come from one table, but only 10 from another - as an extreme example.

Comment: I have no idea what your code has to do with your question.  Please show an example that uses `count(distinct)`.

Comment: Are you just looking for the number of rows in each temp table in each stored procedure or are these not always temp tables? Also, do you need to deal with the joins or would it be enough to say `select Count(*) from #MyTable`. Because, if they are always temp tables and you can do something without having to deal with the joins, I'm thinking if you go outside the box and query the temp table DB at the end of each stored procedure, you might be able to get an answer...

Comment: @JohnBustos No, the tables that are added are just so somebody could use them to produce an example. In reality its real tables and also TVFs. Ideally what I want to see is that 1 billion rows come from 1 or two tables but only a handful come from others, for that particular join condition. I'm going to add that to the question, so thanks for the prompt about what I'm ultimately trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question but have no idea what the code sample has to do with it.  So, this will explain how to get the equivalent functionality for `count(distinct)`.

You can do `count(distinct)` in SQL Server using two levels of window functions.

If you have

```
select count(distinct x) over (partition by y)
from a
```

Then you can do:

```
select a.*,
       max(dr) over (partition by y) as count_distinct
from (select a.*, dense_rank() over (partition by y order by x) as dr
      from a
     ) a
```

Comment: I've updated my question. Basically doing what you suggest for every single table of in every join of every stored procedure is counter productive to the time saving requirement. If it was oracle it'd simply be a case of using rowid, which is an inbuilt identifier for each row and which doesn't require further levels of separate window functions that need to be rejoined in order to use it.